# How make validation of Date with datetime work with jquery(date picker) for php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datetime

Script(jquery) use to make input[date] accessible to multiple browser(datepicker)

```
<script>
   $(function(){           
      if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
    // If not native HTML5 support, fallback to jQuery datePicker <script src="js/realtime_validityScript.js">
           $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
            // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
                **dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',** 
                maxDate: 0

            },
            // Localization
            $.datepicker.regional['it']
        );
    }
});
</script>
```

2- PHP code for validating date format by user in case jquery is disabled (not working) - also not sure how to use DateTime::getLastErrors()

```
// specify your date's original format, in this example d/m/Y (e.g. 25/07/2014)

 **$format = "d-m-Y";**
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['DateField']);
 $date_errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
  if(? $date_errors[also dunno what to put here?] ) {

   // createFromFormat returns false if the format is invalid;

   echo 'Your date format is incorrect';
 } else {
   //change it to any format you want with format() (e.g. 2013-08-31)

    $date->format('Y-m-d');
 }
```

Original PHP code for getting my date: (my db access currently this format "Y-m-d")

```
if (empty($_POST["DateField"]) ) {

   $errors['DateField'] = "Age is required"; 

} else {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['DateField']));

}
```

I also want the input date to be able to convert formats like those ('d-m-Y', 'Y/m/d', 'Y.m.d', 'd.m-Y', 'd/m/Y') to **'Y-m-d'** maybe with an array of some sort?

Note: if i remove the 2- part my code work fine

Thanks you for your support...still new to PHP would really help if someone could expl to me what wrong and what the correct code

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can always edit your question if you want to add or change something.  And if you have another question, post it separately.

Comment: I think I should put if($date_errors['warning_count'] + $date_errors['error_count'] > 0) { instead but still not working my db not gettting any result

Answer (score 1):

Date type will not allow your required formats. so instead of using `type="date"` use `type="text"` and add a class `date` to the input field to initialise datepicker like,

```
....
$('input.date').datepicker({
   // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   maxDate: 0
},
....
```

And change HTML like,

```
<input type="text" class="date" ..../>
```

Comment: Can you clarify in more details what I need to do, please?                         <input type="text" class="date?"  id= 'DateField' name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required/> That all?

Comment: Yes, remove the `?` from class name `date`.

Comment: ? is not present in my code I put it here just to be sure that what you were telling me to do

Comment: It says that Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string?